# What is strategy profile? Is it -a vector list of si or -the cartesian product of Si?

Tags: game-theory

Which one is correct (a) or (b). If one of them is strategy profile then what is the other called. Which is the standard book to follow for such terminology

(a) Some textbooks describe strategy profile as:
A list describing the strategies that each player selects, s = (s1, s2, ..., sN ).For example, in a two-player game between two firms (A and B), a strategy profile could be s = (12, 8) where sA = 12 denotes firm A’s output level while sB = 8 represents firm B’s output.

(b) Other textbooks define it as cartesian product
Mathematically, the set of strategy profiles are defined as S = S1 × S2 × . . . × Sn ie if S1={12,8} and S2={1,10} then S= {(12,1),(12,10),(8,1),(8,10)}.

either s is strategy profile, if so what is S called
or S is strategy profile, if so what is s called
[image: Video on Youtube]

[What is the gentleman trying to tell](https://youtu.be/zkO6HEdh-NU?t=549)

Comment: Did you just answer your title question yourself in the body of the text...?

Comment: @VARulle can you review the question again and recommend a standard textbook which lists the terminology with notation and examples

Comment: @NarayanaSrikanthReddy You can find some book recommendations [here](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/6112/game-theory-textbooks).

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that any textbook defines a strategy profile as a Cartesian product. The standard definition for a finite game is that players $i\in\{1,\ldots,n\}$ have *strategy sets* $S_i$. Then $S=S_1\times S_2\times\cdots\times S_n$ is the *set of strategy profiles*, where a *strategy profile* is an $n$-tuple of strategies $s\in S$.

Comment: Ooops, another answer was posted while I was still typing...

Comment: Room enough for both, thank you for the edit!

Comment: https://youtu.be/zkO6HEdh-NU?t=546 @VARulle please comment

Comment: @NarayanaSrikanthReddy I'm not sure what you want me to comment on. In this video Selcuk says almost exactly what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As @VARulle pointed out, you do give correct information, there is no contradiction.

A strategy profile is a list describing the strategies that each player selects, $s = (s_1, s_2, \dots,  s_n )$.

Each player $i$ has a set of strategies to choose from, we will denote this with $S_i$. The players can choose any of their strategies irrespective of what the others choose, so all combinations are possible. Hence the set of all possible choices is given by the Cartesian product
$$
S = S_1 \times S_2 \times \dots \times S_n.
$$
This is called the *set* of strategy profiles.

**An example**
$$S_1 = \left\{a,b\right\}, \ S_2 = \left\{\alpha,\beta\right\}$$
$$S = S_1 \times S_2 =  \left\{(a,\alpha),(a,\beta),(b,\alpha),(b,\beta)\right\}$$

Comment: https://youtu.be/zkO6HEdh-NU?t=546 check this out and comment please

Comment: Hi @NarayanaSrikanthReddy ! My comment is: "No way, please make questions self contained."